# How to use the deviceCheck task to run tests on remote devices

Tags: android, jenkins, android-studio, gradle, android-espresso

On http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide, the following tasks are defined:

> - **assemble** The task to assemble the output(s) of the project
> - **check** The
>     task to run all the checks.
> - **connectedCheck** Runs checks that requires a
>     connected device or emulator. they will run on all connected devices
>     in parallel.
> - **deviceCheck** Runs checks using APIs to connect to remote
>     devices. This is used on CI servers.
> - **build** This task does both
>     assemble and check
> - **clean** This task cleans the output of the project

I am now setting up a Jenkins CI to run my (Espresso) tests and the **deviceCheck** task description seems related to that. But I couldn't find any further documentation or examples on how to use this task on CI server to execute the tests on a remote device. Does anyone know how to use it?

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe that `deviceCheck` runs every time you're running any test task. It's just a simple verification of the manifest against the devices that were found on the `connectedCheck` task. E.g. API level, `<uses-feature>`, etc. Similar checks that Google Play does before allowing the apk to be downloaded to a device.

Comment: When running "./gradlew -q tasks --all", you can verify all tasks dependencies. No task seems to depend on deviceCheck, so I assume it does not run with connectedCheck. I think the description of the task, informing that it connects to remote devices and is used on CI servers would also be wrong if that was the case.

Comment: well. I upvote and I hope someone with more knowledge come answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend running the tests with: [Spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon). It's easy to setup, has lots of nice out of the box features. e.g. good test reports, screenshots ++.

I am using it on my Jenkins CI, and it works really well! I have connected multiple devices to the CI-server, and the tests runs on all of them.

Comment: Spoon is a little bit untouched for a while, do you know another tool for that job?